# Error OpsHub when try to open all projects in

Tags: visual-studio-2008, azure-devops, opshub

When trying to connect to TFS on-premise and get a list of project - error appeared:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21x93.png)

All logs in attachment by ref: 
https://pastebin.com/x2MmEQTE

Please help to resolve

Comment: What's the version of that tool (About section, I am using v2.5) and TFS? What's the operation system of your machine?

Comment: OpsHub V2.5.0.001.TFS version is 2008. OS version of my PC where installed OpsHub is Windows 10. Is TFS 2008 supported ?

Comment: TFS 2008 is not supported (only TFS 2010 and higher are supported)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of OpsHub tool: [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility), the TFS 2008 isn't included.

> The utility supports the following versions of Team Foundation Server:
>   2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is most likely due to conflicting OM cached data.

Perform the following steps:

- Close all instances of Visual Studio that are open (if any)
- Close the OVSMU application
- Browse to the folder below and delete all the contents of the below folders (Remember, the content and not the folder itself)

1)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache

2)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

3)      %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache

{the folders would exists, based on the version of Visual Studio installed. Do this for whichever folders exist in your case}

Restart the utility and try again.

Comment: No, unfortunately it's does not help.